# TextView android:autoLink="phone" calls android.intent.action.VIEW causing ActivityNotFoundException

Tags: android, android-intent

I want to display phone number and on click it should be able to call.

In my layout:

```
 <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text_phone"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:autoLink="phone" />
```

I have added permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE"/>
```

But on click on phone link it gives exception

```
02-15 03:24:45.533: E/MessageQueue-JNI(8446): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=tel:xxxxxxxxxx (has extras) }
```

Don't know why it sends intent ACTION_VIEW instead it should send ACTION_CALL.

My android version is 4.2.2

Let me know if I am missing something.

Comment: you haven't declare activty in your manifest. @Prakash

Comment: Its not my activity which is not found, the ActivityNotFoundException is about ACTION_VIEW with dat tel:xxxxx

Answer (score 1):

Try to test it with the real device with sim card..!Which can perform the calling task..

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
mobileTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml(" +98999999999") );
```

and also check your manifest if this class is added

also add

```
 android:autoLink="phone"
```

Comment: No it did not make it link! nor call ACTION_CALL activity